# Trying to print the decrease reverse array with while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to find the way to modify my while statement in which it able to print the decrease array of number. Here is my code:

```
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let count = 0;
while (count <= list.length) {
    console.log(list.slice(0, count++).join(' '));
}

while (count >= list.length){
  console.log(list.slice(count--,0).join(' '));
}
```

Output:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Correct Output:

```
1 
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1
3 2 1
2 1
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the array

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let count = 0;
while (count <= list.length) {
    console.log(list.slice(0, count++).join(' '));
}
let list_reverse = list;
list_reverse.reverse();
count = 0;
while (count <= list.length){
  console.log(list_reverse.slice(count++).join(' '));
}
```